# How to correctly update entities in EF4 using POCO and custom ObjectContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Using the technique described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments) I have a simple POCO EF4 model up and running. Saving new and deleting is straightforward (using `AddObject()` and `DeleteObject()` respectively). But the only way of updating objects I have found is to retrieve the stored version of the object and manually update its properties with new values from the object being saved. Surely there is a better way?

My `ObjectContext` is disconnected - in otherwords, I use a new `ObjectContext` instance for each operation on the model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the *stub technique*:

```
public void UpdateOrder(Order o)
{
   var stub = new Order { Id = o.OrderId }; // create stub with EntityKey
   ctx.Orders.Attach(stub); // attach stub to graph
   ctx.ApplyCurrentValues("Orders", o); // override stub with values.
   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

If the entity is already in the graph, you will get an OSM exception (entity with key already exists).

I counteract this by checking if the object exists in the graph first (TryGetObjectStateEntry) and only attaching if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. Do you mean 'if the *stub* is already in the graph', or if `Order o` is already in the graph?

Comment: Either. Each entity on your model has an "EntityKey"  which uniquely identifies it - like an "OrderID". If this entity is already in the graph (either by a previous .Attach, or retrieving it from a query) with the same entity key, it will throw an exception. If you say you new up on OC each time, it shouldn't be an issue though (although you haven't mentioned if this is a web app/windows/etc)

Comment: It's MVC and it seems to be updating fine and throwing no EMs using your technique.

Comment: By the way, do you know any good EF books or resources? You seem to know your stuff.. :)

Comment: Hehe, yeah i do allright - i'm just a quick learner, only been working with EF for a few months. *Highly* recommend Julia Lerman's book - http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Entity-Framework-Julia-Lerman/dp/059652028X. It's the only book on EF you need. She rocks.